# Error in number formatting in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I need to format the numbers in a column like this:

08146.000331/2021-32

But, when I use the following format

```
00000"."000000"/"0000"-"00
```

The result is

08146.000331/2021-3**0**

What am I doing wrong?

There is a formula to achieve the aimed result?

This is the actual sheet: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q1efCfyJOGjJetMGVKrDK6I3ZDQB3PWkaXzUArg9oqo/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Just done it. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q1efCfyJOGjJetMGVKrDK6I3ZDQB3PWkaXzUArg9oqo/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the values in column `C` are numbers and some are text strings that look like numbers.

Click in column `C` and choose **Insert > Column right** to create a new column `D`. Then insert this formula in cell `D4`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  { 
    "Formatted SEI"; 
    regexreplace(trim(C5:C); "^(\d{5})(\d{6})(\d{4})(\d{2})$"; "$1.$2/$3-$4") 
  } 
)
```

The formula converts all values to text strings and inserts separators.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try
     000"."000"."000"-"00          ---> for CPF, and
     00"."000"."000"/"0000"-"00    ---> for CNPJ.

For numbers with more then 14 digits, this type of formatting don't works due to numeric precision limit.

Um abraço.
```

Comment: I don't want to format like a cpf nor a cnpj

Comment: Sorry !
I  tested with 1000000000000000  (10 ^15) and works good.
But with   1000000000000001  (10^15 + 1) the last significant digit turn to 0.
It seems to be a limit of number precision (15 digits).
Note that at this point the cell lost formatting and go to left, like a string, not a number.